# C array of integers represented as bits converted to a decimal

Tags: c, arrays, binary, bit

If i have length of 20 2d  array

of length 5 integers represented as bits

```
int bitsval[6];
```

and the array looks like for example  bitsval = {0,0,1,0,1,0}

and i want the decimal value so     something like

(2^0 x 0) + ( 2^1 x 1) + (2^2 x 0)...  and eventually return the final value as 10

can some one help write a function a function like this

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it shows no attempt at solving the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a homework question, so I'll help, but not give you the code

What you need to do is have a 'total' variable, and a 'current bit worth' variable.

Start with the 'current bit worth' variable equal to 32 (2 ^ 5)

Then, have a loop going through the array, adding the bit worth on to the total if that bit is '1'

Each time you go to the next element in the array you need to half the 'current bit worth' value

[Edit]

OK - if it's not homework, try this:

```
total = 0;
bitvalue= 32;
for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
  if (bitsval[i]) total += bitvalue;
  bitvalue /= 2;
}
```

Comment: its not really a homework question its a small tool i need for a much bigger program im building im on the right track i sorta understand that i need something like this but im getting messed up when it gets to 2^0 and 2^1 :(

Comment: OK, if it's not homework, I've added sample code to my answer

Answer (score 0):

This should work I guess.

```
#include<math.h>
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
int a[]={1,0,0,1,0};
int sum=0;
for(int i=0; i<sizeof(a)/2; i++)
{
 if(a[i]==1)
 sum+=pow(2,(sizeof(a)/2)-i-1);
}
}
```

Comment: a) Using pow() is very inefficient

b) This won't work if ints aren't 2 bytes - use "sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])" instead

Answer (score 0):

Without going into any kind of binary, and working of off of purely your explanation here is something that should work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(){

  int number[6] = {0,0,1,0,1,0}, result = 0;

  for (int x = 5; x >= 0; --x){

    result += (number[x] * (int) pow(2, 5-x));

  }

  printf("Final result: %d\n", result);

  return 0;

}
```

You will off course have to massage it to fit